# getting data from array within an object

Tags: php, arrays, object

how would i go about extracting the data from the ["Actions"] array below:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (4) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["Type"]=>
    string(8) "Campaign"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(28) "An unmissable invitation for"
    ["Actions"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#6 (4) {
        ["Event"]=>
        string(4) "Open"
        ["Date"]=>
        string(19) "2013-04-30 19:01:00"
        ["IPAddress"]=>
        string(14) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        ["Detail"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
```

i can extract anything above that array by doing the following:

```
foreach($result->response as $entry) { 

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$entry->ID.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$entry->Type.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$entry->Name.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$entry->Actions["Event"][0].'</td>';

        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: use the `$entry->Actions[0]["Event"]` to get data from action array.

Comment: i have stied this and get Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: getting your point here you should use the `$entry->Actions[0]->Event`.